# Cannot insert an image - Textfield

Tags: orchardcms

I downloaded the new version of Orchard - 1.4.2.
Created a new Content Type. Added a new Text Field. Changed the flavour to HTML. 
However, I can't insert an image to that WSIWYG. There is no error. But the Image Picker tool doesn't seem to work.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in the later versions.